# Handling multiple account logins?

Tags: wp-admin, login

Because my role at work requires me to post articles for coworkers, I have the need to logout and login using different accounts.  WP's cookies sometimes won't allow me to.  Even have tried Incognito, but doesn't always help.

Answer (score 0):

In the post edit screen, you can enable the **Author** metabox by going to the screen options.

With the Author metabox and the right role, you can set the author of a post to another user without having to switch to their respective account.

**Add New/Edit Post**
[image: Edit Post Screenshot]

**Author Metabox**
[image]